# How to distribute kafka load into openshift pods using kafka partitions

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, openshift

I have a spring boot application  and I would like to distribute the load of a Kafka topic into 3 open-shift pods. I have the following example where I can listen from 3 Kafka partitions on three different threads, this spring boot application will load into one openshift pod. But I want  to be a able to listen from one Kafka partition on one pod so when I load 3 pods on open-shift each pod will listen from one Kafka partition. This will allow me to scale the application to N partitions on N pods.  I am not sure if this is possible or if need to use a different approach. Thanks

```
public class DepAcctInqConsumerController {
   
   private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DepAcctInqConsumerController.class);

   @Value("${kafka.topic.acct-info.request}")
   private String requestTopic;

  @KafkaListener(id = "id-0",containerFactory = "requestReplyListenerContainerFactory",
          topicPartitions = { @TopicPartition(topic = "${kafka.topic.acct-info.request}", partitions = "0" )})
  public Message<?> listenPartition0(InGetAccountInfo accountInfo, @Header(KafkaHeaders.REPLY_TOPIC) byte[] replyTo,
                           @Header(KafkaHeaders.CORRELATION_ID) byte[] correlation,@Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) int id) {

    try {

      LOGGER.info("Received request for partition id = " +  id);

      AccountInquiryDto accountInfoDto  = getAccountInquiryDto(accountInfo);

      return MessageBuilder.withPayload(accountInfoDto)
              .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.TOPIC, replyTo)
              .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID, id)
              .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.CORRELATION_ID, correlation)
              .build();


    } catch (Exception e) {
      LOGGER.error(e.toString(),e);
    }

    return null;
  }


  @KafkaListener(id = "id-1",containerFactory = "requestReplyListenerContainerFactory",
          topicPartitions = { @TopicPartition(topic = "${kafka.topic.acct-info.request}", partitions = "#{@finder.partitions(${kafka.topic.acct-info.request)}" )})
  public Message<?> listenPartition1(InGetAccountInfo accountInfo, @Header(KafkaHeaders.REPLY_TOPIC) byte[] replyTo,
                           @Header(KafkaHeaders.CORRELATION_ID) byte[] correlation,@Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) int id) {

    try {

      LOGGER.info("Received request for partition id = " +  id);

      AccountInquiryDto accountInfoDto  = getAccountInquiryDto(accountInfo);

      return MessageBuilder.withPayload(accountInfoDto)
              .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.TOPIC, replyTo)
              .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID, id)
              .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.CORRELATION_ID, correlation)
              .build();


    } catch (Exception e) {
      LOGGER.error(e.toString(),e);
    }

    return null;
  }

  @KafkaListener(id = "id-2",containerFactory = "requestReplyListenerContainerFactory",
          topicPartitions = { @TopicPartition(topic = "${kafka.topic.acct-info.request}", partitions =  "2" )})
  public Message<?> listenPartition2(InGetAccountInfo accountInfo, @Header(KafkaHeaders.REPLY_TOPIC) byte[] replyTo,
                           @Header(KafkaHeaders.CORRELATION_ID) byte[] correlation, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) int id) {

    try {

      LOGGER.info("Received request for partition id = " +  id);

      AccountInquiryDto accountInfoDto  = getAccountInquiryDto(accountInfo);

      return MessageBuilder.withPayload(accountInfoDto)
              .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.TOPIC, replyTo)
              .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID, id)
              .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.CORRELATION_ID, correlation)
              .build();


    } catch (Exception e) {
      LOGGER.error(e.toString(),e);
    }

    return null;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

We don't need to have multiple kafka listeners for each partition. We just need one listener.

- If you are running single pod, messages from all three partitions will be consumed by that single pod,
- If you run more than 1 pod, partitions will be distributed across pods.
- We can run as many pods as no of partitions.

All Pods must use same consumer group name.

This is all we need.

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.topic.acct-info.request}")
public void receive(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record)
```